# SQL Insert Command and Mysqli_query

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Why is it that if I look to Insert Data in the Database with the following:

```
   $q = "INSERT INTO users 
        (entry_id,fname,lname,username,email,town,plz,password,member_since,visits)
         VALUES 
        (0,'$first_name','$last_name','$username','$email','$town','$plz','$password',NOW(),1)";
```

and I don´t add the line of code:

```
$r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
```

afterwards, the information is not updated to the database?

Thanks in advance.

Robin

Comment: how do you expect it to be inserted into the database without executing it?

Comment: The first statement does not actually talk to the database at all. It merely defines the variable `$q` containing  a string that happens to be a SQL statement.  `mysqli_query()` accepts as a parameter a text string SQL statement. That string is often created first as a variable, which is what your `$q` does.

Comment: Are you seriously asking why data isn't inserted into the database if you don't execute the query?  Or something else?

Comment: It's important to remember, and not always obvious at first, that PHP and the MySQL server are _entirely separate entities_. The MySQL server takes SQL statements as input, and your PHP code is capable of supplying those statements. In the end, PHP itself is not involved in insert/retrieval with the database. PHP only asks the MySQL server to perform actions and pass the results back.  `mysqli_query()` is one of the avenues of communication.

Comment: Thank you for your extended reply. It has been very helpful and well explained.

Answer (score 0):

`$q` is just a string. If you don't use `mysqli_query` (or something equivalent) to execute it against a database, there's no way the database will even "know" it exists, let alone act upon it.